# Dropdown Menu in flutter from json Api

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an Api Which I want to show in my drop down menu of flutter app.

I am able to get lists in simple Text widget but not able to fetch in DropDownButton.

Here is  sample of my code

```
_getAllCategories() async {
    var categories = await _categoryService.getCategories();
    var _list = json.decode(categories.body);
    List<Category> results = [];
    _list['data'].forEach((data) {
      var model = Category();
      model.id = data["id"];
      model.name = data["categoryName"];
      model.icon = data["categoryIcon"];
      results.add(model);
    });
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _categoryList = results;
      });
    }
  }
```

and I am getting my result using

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _categoryList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return Text(_categoryList[index].name,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),);
          },
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand whats the problem. Have you tried to use [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a simple dropdown widget like this:

```
    
  List<Category> _categoryList = List<Category>();

  Category dropdownValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return DropdownButton<Category>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (Category newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue;
        });
      },
      items: _categoryList.map<DropdownMenuItem<Category>>((Category value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<Category>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value.name),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}

class Category {
  String name;
  String icon;
  int id;
}
```